# ADT project creating error

Tags: android, api, adt

I would like to create a new project in ADT, but I can not do this, I always get similar messages to this:

> This template requires a build target API version of at least 14, and
>   the current version is 10

I would like to use Android 2.3.3 to build.

Comment: Are you trying to set any Theme while creating new Project ? If so then select theme as "none"

Comment: Yes, I have selected theme "none".

Comment: @lal how he post his code, he is struggling to create a project

Comment: oo..ok ok..Are you using adt to make the project??

Comment: Yes, I would like to create a new project. It was working earlier perfectly, but now not.

Answer (score 0):

> This template requires a build target API version of at least 14, and the current version is 10

Here it is clearly saying that your trying to use a template which requires minimum of API level 14 but you mentioned API level 10 as in your manifest file. So go to Android manifest file and change target SDK version to 14

like:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

Comment: Okay, but this file is unique in every project. Or not?

Comment: But I can not create a new project with Activity, so I can not change this. :/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have updated the SDK manager upto the recent API level and you can set minSDK version to 10 and target SDKVersion as 14..Also set Theme as None because you are probably using a HoloTheme...